# Add a dynamic key => value options in 3 level array option

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as main options in my code.

In case, I want to add dynamic key => values into specific options array key.

This is my main options array:

```
$configarray1 = array(
    "name" => "Addon",
    "description" => "module for whmcs",
    "version" => "1.1",
    "author" => "Me",
    "language" => "english",
    "fields" => array(
        "sender" => array (
            "FriendlyName" => "Sender", 
            "Type" => "dropdown", 
            "Options" => strtolower($GatewaysIM), 
            "Description" => $getBalance, 
            "Default" => $Defaultsender, 
        ),
        "validateday" => array (
            "FriendlyName" => "Days for Re-validation", 
            "Type" => "text", 
            "Size" => "25",
            "Description" => "", 
            "Default" => "90",
        ),
    )    
);
```

I want to add this sender array options in configarray1 fields key:

```
if($sender == 'sender1'){
        $configarray2['fields'] = array(
            "username" => array (
                "FriendlyName" => "username", 
                "Type" => "text", 
                "Size" => "25",
                "Description" => "", 
                "Default" => "", 
            ),
            "password" => array (
                "FriendlyName" => "password", 
                "Type" => "password", 
                "Size" => "25",
                "Description" => "", 
                "Default" => "", 
            )
        );
} elseif($sender == 'sender2'){
        $configarray2['fields'] = array(
            "line" => array (
                "FriendlyName" => "line", 
                "Type" => "text", 
                "Size" => "25",
                "Description" => "", 
                "Default" => "", 
            )
        );
}
```

Output array must be like this below when sender is sender1:

```
$configarray = array(
    "name" => "Addon",
    "description" => "module for whmcs",
    "version" => "1.1",
    "author" => "Me",
    "language" => "english",
    "fields" => array(
        "sender" => array (
            "FriendlyName" => "Sender", 
            "Type" => "dropdown", 
            "Options" => strtolower($GatewaysIM), 
            "Description" => $getBalance, 
            "Default" => $Defaultsender, 
        ),
        "username" => array (
            "FriendlyName" => "username", 
            "Type" => "text", 
            "Size" => "25",
            "Description" => "", 
            "Default" => "", 
        ),
        "password" => array (
            "FriendlyName" => "password", 
            "Type" => "password", 
            "Size" => "25",
            "Description" => "", 
            "Default" => "", 
        ),
        "validateday" => array (
            "FriendlyName" => "Days for Re-validation", 
            "Type" => "text", 
            "Size" => "25",
            "Description" => "", 
            "Default" => "90",
        ),
    )    
);
```

I tested array push but this adds a key in arrays first place and not in 'fields' key, my code was this $configarray = array_push($configarray1,$configarray2); but this not works !

I also tested sum of two arrays ($configarray = $configarray1 + $configarray2) but this is the same as array_push and returns wrong output for me.

How can i resolve this problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

You should just declare it. You don't need a new variable.

Assuming you have the original array named as $configarray1, just:

```
if($sender == 'sender1'){
    $configarray1['fields']['username'] = array(
        "FriendlyName" => "username", 
        "Type" => "text", 
        "Size" => "25",
        "Description" => "", 
        "Default" => "", 
   );
   $configarray1['fields']['password'] => array(
        "FriendlyName" => "password", 
        "Type" => "password", 
        "Size" => "25",
        "Description" => "", 
        "Default" => "", 
   );
} elseif($sender == 'sender2'){
   $configarray1['fields']['line'] = array (
        "FriendlyName" => "line", 
        "Type" => "text", 
        "Size" => "25",
        "Description" => "", 
        "Default" => "", 
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @subzeta. This not works unfortunately !
The output is just configarray1.